# How can Feynman diagrams be used to calculate this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, graph-theory

How can Feynman diagrams be used to calculate the following integral up to order $g^4$?

$$Z(g) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \int_{-\infty}^\infty dy e^{-\frac{x^2}{2} -\frac{y^2}{2} + \frac{g}{4}x^2y^2}$$

Comment: Write $\exp(g(xy)^2/4)$ to order $g^4$, viz.$$Z(g)=\sum_{n=0}^4\frac{g^n}{n!4^n}\int_{\Bbb R^2}dxdy(xy)^{2n}\exp(-(x^2+y^2)/2)+o(g^4).$$Now you just need to evaluate $5$ integrals, $1$ of which should be familiar. There's no need to use Feynman diagrams.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment. That makes sense. Actually the integral is not that bad and I can solve it using various methods. But I was explicitly asked to "calculate it using Feynman diagrams" and I don't know what that means. Do you know by any chance?

Comment: I think that language implies a desire to compute the terms by a combinatorics approach such as [Wick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick%27s_theorem). See e.g. Secs. 1.1.3, 1.1.4 & 7.2-7.5 [here](https://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/JohnChalker/theory/lecture-notes.pdf).

Comment: Feynman diagrams are a Physics concept. You would be better off asking in the Physics forum.